# Can someone explain easily what pool-hopping is and explain proportional system?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, pool-hopping

I've been reading several articles but still can't understand the concept of pool-hopping. How are the shares distributed in the proportional method that is vulnerable against pool hopping? How are the shares submitted at the beginning of a round is worth more? and if a miner leaves a pool, won't it's rewarding stop. so it won't take any profit?